# function that returns which team has the most wins

Tags: python

How can I write a function that takes a two-dimensional sequence as an argument and returns which team earned the most wins? when multiple teams earn the same amount of wins, it should return the first team's serial number.

It should return something like this:

```
who_won([['W', 'W', 'W'], ['L', 'L', 'L'], ['W', 'W', 'L'], ['L', 'L', 'W']])
1
```

ㅤ

```
who_won([['L', 'W', 'L'], ['W', 'W', 'L'], ['L', 'W', 'W'], ['L', 'W', 'L']])
2
```

Here's what I have right now:

```
def who_won(matrix):
w_counter = 0
for x in matrix:
    for y in x:
        if 'W' in x:
            W_counter += 1
```

Comment: _my programme counts all wins_ We can't point out what you did wrong if you don't show us the function...

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `max` operator, sorting rows by their number of wins, and using their `i`-index position `matrix[i]` as a secondary parameter (to decide in case of draws).

```
def who_won(matrix):
    return 1 + max(range(len(matrix)), key = lambda i: [matrix[i].count('W'),-i])

# print(who_won([['W', 'W', 'W'], ['L', 'L', 'L'], ['W', 'W', 'L'], ['L', 'L', 'W']]))
# 1
# 
# print(who_won([['L', 'W', 'L'], ['W', 'W', 'L'], ['L', 'W', 'W'], ['L', 'W', 'L']]))
# 2
```

---

Your original code should look something like:

```
def who_won(matrix):
    record       = 0
    index_record = None
    for i,x in enumerate(matrix,1):
        w_counter = 0
        for y in x:
            if y == 'W':
                w_counter += 1
        if w_counter > record:
            record       = w_counter
            index_record = i
    return index_record
```

Comment: Always use a `def` statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a `lambda` expression directly to an identifier ([PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations))

Comment: Ok, sorry, now it is a proper function :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following(I assumed "Draw"(D) is also an option):

```py
def count_points(lst: list) -> int:
    return sum(3 if i == "W" else 1 if i == "D" else 0 for i in lst)


def who_won(lst: list[list]) -> int:
    winner_team = max(lst, key=count_points)
    return lst.index(winner_team) + 1


print(who_won([["W", "W", "W"], ["L", "L", "L"], ["W", "W", "L"], ["L", "L", "W"]]))
print(who_won([["L", "W", "L"], ["W", "W", "L"], ["L", "W", "W"], ["L", "W", "L"]]))
```

output:

```
1
2
```

`count_points` counts the point of each team. `who_won` finds the `max` based on what is returned from `count_points`.

`.index()` returns the first team as you requested. (plus 1 because of zero-based indexing)

---

As noted in comment, if you only have `'W'` and `'L'` you can simplify return value of `count_points` to:

```py
return sum(i == "W" for i in lst)
```

Comment: Why are you adding 3 instead of 1 in the sum? Also, are you aware that the default start value of sum is 0, and you can therefore add bools directly, without using the ternary operator?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I had `"w" -> 3`, `"D" -> 1`, `"L" -> 0` in my mind when I was writing. But you're right, OP didn't ask for. It's enough.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
results = [['W', 'W', 'W'], ['L', 'L', 'L'], ['W', 'W', 'L'], ['L', 'L', 'W']]

def get_winning_team_idx(results):
# 1- Convert 'W's in the lists to 1s, and everything else to 0s and sum over each team
    wins = [sum([1 if r == 'W' else 0 for r in team]) for team in results]
# 2- Find the maximum of the list
    max_win = max(wins)
# 3- Find the index of the maximum wins (the index of the wining team)
    win_team_idx = wins.index(max_win)
    return win_team_idx

get_winning_team_idx(results)
```

Output:

```
0
```

If you want the numbering starting from 1 not 0, just add (+ 1) in the return statement of the function.